# Uso de promesas en NODE.JS // console.log imprime el resultado muchas veces

Tags: javascript, nodejs, promesas

Estoy haciendo un programa que toma un arreglo de links y regresa cuantos sirven y cuantos están rotos. Lo estoy probando con un arreglo que tiene 4 links que funcionan y 2 que no. Aquí está mi código:

```
function getBrokenLinks(linksArr){
    let links = linksArr
    let brokenLinks = 0
    links.forEach(link => {
        fetch(link.href)
            .then( res => {
                if ( res.status != 200 ){
                    brokenLinks++
                }
            }).then( () => {console.log(brokenLinks)})
    })
    return brokenLinks
}
```

esto es lo que recibo en la consola:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cU5p.png)

Quiero que la consola imprima el total de los links rotos sólo una vez, después de que la función haya buscado los links

Answer (score 0):

Esto se debe a que estas ejecutando el console.log dentro del ciclo forEach, lo que deberías hacer es ejecutarlo fuera, debido a que se trata de una petición fetch ocupas hacer que el código ejecuta de forma sincronía para poder imprimir el resultado al final

```
async function getBrokenLinks(linksArr){
    let links = linksArr
    let brokenLinks = 0
    for(let i in links){
        try {
            let link = links[i]
            await fetch(link.href)
        }catch(err){
            brokenLinks++
        }
    }
    console.log(brokenLinks)
    return brokenLinks
}
```